# currently having connection problem between the server and the client in socket + pygame code

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

when i receive the turn in my client its just getting stuck and the program isnt continuing even tho its in a thread
ive trying debugging for a week and im not getting anywhere id like to get some help on fixing this problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJMaD.png)
this is the shapes

```
import pygame

RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
LEN = 10

class line():
    def __init__(self, sxy, fxy, color):
        self.sxy = sxy # start xy
        self.fxy = fxy # finish xy
        self.color = color


    def PrintLine(self,screen):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, self.color, self.sxy, self.fxy, LEN)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

this is the client

```
import pygame
from thread import *
from socket import *
from Shapes import line
import time
import os

continue_var = False
LEFT = 1
BLUE = (0,0,255)
RED = (255,0,0)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
start = "openscreen.png"
win = "win.png"
lose = "Lose.png"
lobby = "lobby.png"
Board3 = "threeonthree.png"
Board4 = "fouronfour.png"
pick = "pick.png"
disconected = "Opponentdis.png"
images_arr = [start, win, lose, lobby, Board3, Board4, pick, disconected]

def Get_Images(client_socket):
    for image in images_arr:
        data_length = int(client_socket.recv(64).decode('utf-8'))
        image_data = client_socket.recv(1024)
        data_length -= 1024
        while data_length >= 1024:
            image_data += client_socket.recv(1024)
            data_length -= 1024
        image_data += client_socket.recv(data_length)
        with open('clientimg/' + image, 'wb') as current_file:
            current_file.write(image_data)
    print ("GOT ALL THE IMGS")

def save_images():
    global start, win, lose, lobby, Board3, Board4, pick, disconected
    start = "clientimg/" + start
    win = "clientimg/" + win
    lose = "clientimg/" + lose
    lobby = "clientimg/" + lobby
    Board3 = "clientimg/" + Board3
    Board4 = "clientimg/" + Board4
    pick = "clientimg/" + pick
    disconected = "clientimg/" + disconected

def wait_to_receive(client_socket):
    global continue_var
    client_socket.settimeout(0.1)
    while not continue_var:
        try:
            message = receive_a_message(client_socket)
            if message == "no":
                continue_var = False
            elif message == "yes":
                continue_var = True
        except:
            continue_var = False
    client_socket.settimeout(None)

def wait_to_receive_game(client_socket):
    finish = False
    message = ""
    client_socket.settimeout(0.1)
    while not finish:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                finish = True
                pygame.quit()
            else:
                try:
                    message = receive_a_message(client_socket)
                    if message != "":
                        finish = True
                except:
                    finish = False
    client_socket.settimeout(None)
    return message

def checkclick(xclick, yclick, screen):
    white = (254, 252, 254)
    if screen.get_at((xclick, yclick)) != white:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def get_pos_from_msg(msg):
    print msg
    msg = msg.split("|")
    pos = msg[0]
    pos = pos.replace("(", "").replace(")", "")
    pos = pos.split(",")
    print pos
    xstart, ystart = int(pos[0]), int(pos[1])
    pos = msg[1]
    pos = pos.replace("(", "").replace(")", "")
    pos = pos.split(",")
    xend, yend = int(pos[0]), int(pos[1])
    return (xstart, ystart), (xend, yend)

def build_a_message(place, score):
    # your turn / his turn | win / lose else blank | place of the other guy placement / blank | his points | your points
    return place+"|"+score

def send_a_message(server, message):
    print "message sent: " + message
    server.send(message)

def receive_a_message(server):
    message = server.recv(1024)
    print "message: " + message
    return message

def spectating(server):
    pass

def enter_and_send_your_name():
    return

def invited_by_player(screen):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("Showcard Gothic", 40)
    finish = False
    decline = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (200 ,0,0), (58, 363, 211, 145), 0)
    text_decline = font.render("decline", True, (0, 0, 0))
    text_rect_decline = text_decline.get_rect(center=(162, 439))
    accept = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 200, 0), (269, 363, 213, 145), 0)
    text_accept = font.render("accept", True, (0, 0, 0))
    text_rect_accept = text_accept.get_rect(center=(375, 439))
    screen.blit(text_decline, text_rect_decline)
    screen.blit(text_accept, text_rect_accept)
    pygame.display.flip()
    mouse_pos_list = []
    while not finish:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            else:
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == LEFT:
                    mouse_pos_list.append(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
                    finish = True
                    if decline.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        print("text on decline")
                    if accept.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        print("text on accept")

def placeclick(x, y, map):

    if map == 3:
        fory = 283
        fory2 = 311
        yprint = 297
        for i in xrange(3):
            if 170 < x < 255 and fory < y < fory2:
                return (170, yprint), (255, yprint)  # [x start, y start] [x finish, y finish]
            if 283 < x < 368 and fory < y < fory2:
                return (283, yprint), (368, yprint)
            yprint = yprint + 99
            fory2 = fory2 + 99
            fory = fory + 99

        forx = 141
        forx2 = 170
        xprint = 156
        for i in xrange(3):
            if forx < x < forx2 and 382 < y < 411:
                return (xprint, 382), (xprint, 411)
            if forx < x < forx2 and 481 < y < 510:
                return (xprint, 481), (xprint, 510)
            forx = forx + 113
            forx2 = forx2 + 113
            xprint = xprint + 113

        return 0

    if map == 4:
        fory = 241
        fory2 = 269
        yprint = 255
        for i in xrange(3):
            if 113 < x < 198 and fory < y < fory2:
                return (113, yprint), (198, yprint)  # [x start, y start] [x finish, y finish]
            if 226 < x < 311 and fory < y < fory2:
                return (226, yprint), (311, yprint)
            if 340 < x < 425 and fory < y < fory2:
                return (340, yprint), (425, yprint)
            yprint = yprint + 99
            fory2 = fory2 + 99
            fory = fory + 99

        #fourth row
        if 113 < x < 198 and 553 < y < 581:
            return (113, 567), (198, 567)
        if 226 < x < 311 and 553 < y < 581:
            return (226, 567), (311, 567)
        if 340 < x < 425 and 553 < y < 581:
            return (340, 567), (425, 567)

        forx = 85
        forx2 = 113
        xprint = 99
        for i in xrange(4):
            if forx < x < forx2 and 268 < y < 340:
                return (xprint, 268), (xprint, 340)
            if forx < x < forx2 and 368 < y < 439:
                return (xprint, 368), (xprint, 439)
            if forx < x < forx2 and 467 < y < 553:
                return (xprint, 467), (xprint, 553)
            forx = forx + 113
            forx2 = forx2 + 113
            xprint = xprint + 113

        return 0

def checkscore(screen,map):
    score = 0
    if map == 3:
        xrow = 212
        yrow = 294
        xcol = 156
        ycol = 354
        for i in xrange(2):
            if (checkclick(xrow, yrow, screen) == False and checkclick(xrow, yrow + 99, screen) == False and checkclick(xcol, ycol, screen) == False and checkclick(xcol + 113, ycol, screen) == False):
                score = score + 1
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (119, 173, 59), pygame.Rect(xrow - 46, yrow + 9, 95, 85))
                pygame.display.flip()
            yrow = yrow + 99
            ycol = ycol + 100

        xrow = 326
        yrow = 297
        xcol = 269
        ycol = 354
        for i in xrange(2):
            if (checkclick(xrow, yrow, screen) == False and checkclick(xrow, yrow + 99, screen) == False and checkclick(xcol, ycol, screen) == False and checkclick(xcol + 113, ycol, screen) == False):
                score = score + 1
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (119, 173, 59), pygame.Rect(xrow - 46, yrow + 9, 95, 85))
                pygame.display.flip()

            yrow = yrow + 99
            ycol = ycol + 100

        return score

    if map == 4:
        xrow = 156
        yrow = 255
        xcol = 99
        ycol = 311
        for i in xrange(2):
            if (checkclick(xrow, yrow, screen) == False and checkclick(xrow, yrow + 99, screen) == False and checkclick(xcol, ycol, screen) == False and checkclick(xcol+113, ycol, screen) == False):
                score = score + 1
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (119,173,59), pygame.Rect(xrow - 46, yrow + 9, 95, 85))
                pygame.display.flip()
            yrow = yrow + 99
            ycol = ycol + 100

        xrow = 269
        yrow = 255
        xcol = 212
        ycol = 311
        for i in xrange(2):
            if (checkclick(xrow, yrow, screen) == False and checkclick(xrow, yrow + 99, screen) == False and checkclick(xcol, ycol, screen) == False and checkclick(xcol+113, ycol, screen) == False):
                score = score + 1
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (119,173,59), pygame.Rect(xrow - 46, yrow + 9, 95, 85))
                pygame.display.flip()

            yrow = yrow + 99
            ycol = ycol + 100

        xrow = 382
        yrow = 255
        xcol = 326
        ycol = 311
        for i in xrange(2):
            if (checkclick(xrow, yrow, screen) == False and checkclick(xrow, yrow + 99, screen) == False and checkclick(xcol, ycol, screen) == False and checkclick(xcol+113, ycol, screen) == False):
                score = score + 1
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (119,173,59), pygame.Rect(xrow - 46, yrow + 9, 95, 85))
                pygame.display.flip()
            yrow = yrow + 99
            ycol = ycol + 100

        xrow = 156
        yrow = 453
        xcol = 99
        ycol = 511
        for i in xrange(3):
            if (checkclick(xrow, yrow, screen) == False and checkclick(xrow, yrow + 114, screen) == False and checkclick(xcol, ycol, screen) == False and checkclick(xcol+113, ycol, screen) == False):
                score = score + 1
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (119,173,59), pygame.Rect(xrow - 46, yrow + 9, 95, 93))
                pygame.display.flip()
            xrow = xrow + 113
            xcol = xcol + 113

        return score

def pickamap(screen, client):
    mouse_pos_list = []
    LEFT = 1
    img = pygame.image.load(pick)
    screen.blit(img, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    finish = False
    while not finish:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                client.close()
                pygame.quit()
            else:
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == LEFT:
                    mouse_pos_list.append(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
                    if 56 < pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] < 269 and 361 < pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] < 546:
                        client.send(str(3))
                        return 3
                    if 269 < pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] < 546 and 361 < pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] < 546:
                        client.send(str(4))
                        return 4

def game_function(screen,client,text):
    client.send("ready")
    print "sent"

    map_recieve = client.recv(1)
    map = int(map_recieve)
    if map == 3:
        img = pygame.image.load(Board3)
    else:
        img = pygame.image.load(Board4)
    screen.blit(img, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()

    scorered = 0
    scoreblue = 0
    score = 0
    mouse_pos_list = []
    placementarr = []
    finish = False
    while not finish:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                finish = True
            else:
                message = wait_to_receive_game(client)
                message = message.split("@")
                print message
                for message_now in message:
                    if message_now != "":
                        print message_now
                        message_now = message_now.split("|")
                        turn = message_now[0]

                        if turn == "0":
                            img = pygame.image.load(disconected)
                            screen.blit(img, (0, 0))
                            pygame.display.flip()


                        if message_now[1] == "0" and  message_now[2] == "0":
                            place1 = 0
                            place2 = 0
                        else:
                            place1, place2 = get_pos_from_msg(message_now[1] + "|" + message_now[2])

                        if turn == "His turn":
                            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (254, 252, 254), pygame.Rect(397, 620, 200, 200))
                            pygame.display.flip()
                            label = text.render("Player 2", True, RED)
                            screen.blit(label, (400, 620))
                            pygame.display.flip()
                            if place1 == 0 and place2 == 0:
                                break
                            else:
                                liner = line(place1, place2, RED)
                                liner.PrintLine(screen)
                                if checkscore(screen, map) > score:
                                    scorered = scorered + (checkscore(screen, map) - score)
                                    score = checkscore(screen, map)
                                    label = text.render(str(scorered), True, BLACK)
                                    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (254, 252, 254), pygame.Rect(468, 143, 50, 60))
                                    pygame.display.flip()
                                    screen.blit(label, (468, 136))
                                    pygame.display.flip()

                        if turn == "Your turn":
                            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (254, 252, 254), pygame.Rect(397, 620, 200, 200))
                            pygame.display.flip()
                            label = text.render("Player 1", True, BLUE)
                            screen.blit(label, (400, 620))
                            pygame.display.flip()
                            finish_input = False
                            while not finish_input:
                                for event in pygame.event.get():
                                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                                        finish_input = True
                                        client.close()
                                        pygame.quit()
                                    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == LEFT:
                                        mouse_pos_list.append(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
                                        continuevar = True
                                        if checkclick(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0], pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1], screen) == True and placeclick(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0], pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1], map) != 0:
                                            help = placeclick(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0], pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1], map)
                                            for x in placementarr:
                                                if x == help:
                                                    continuevar = False
                                            placementarr.append(help)
                                            if continuevar == True:
                                                help1, help2 = placeclick(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0], pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1], map)
                                                message_to_send = str(help1) + "|" + str(help2)
                                                liner = line(help1, help2, BLUE)
                                                liner.PrintLine(screen)
                                                if checkscore(screen, map) > score:
                                                    scoreblue = scoreblue + (checkscore(screen, map) - score)
                                                    score = checkscore(screen, map)
                                                    label = text.render(str(scoreblue), True, BLACK)
                                                    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (254, 252, 254), pygame.Rect(233, 135, 55, 60))
                                                    pygame.display.flip()
                                                    screen.blit(label, (241, 134))
                                                    pygame.display.flip()
                                                message_to_send = message_to_send + "|" + str(score)
                                                send_a_message(client,message_to_send)
                                                finish_input = True
                                                break
                    else:
                        pass


def enter_name_function(screen,client_socket):
    img = pygame.image.load(start)
    screen.blit(img, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("Showcard Gothic", 50)
    text = ""
    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                try:
                    if (str(event.unicode).isalpha() or str(event.unicode).isdigit() or event.unicode == " ") and len(text) < 12:
                        text += event.unicode
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                        if len(text) < 1:
                            run = True
                        else:
                            run = False
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                        text = text[:-1]
                except:
                    pass
            screen.blit(img, (0, 0))
            text_surf = font.render(text, True, (0, 0, 0))
            screen.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(center=screen.get_rect().center))
            pygame.display.flip()
    client_socket.send(text)

def main():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 8888  # socket server port number
    WINDOW_WIDTH = 540
    WINDOW_HEIGHT = 690
    pygame.init()
    text_font_waiting = pygame.font.SysFont("Showcard Gothic", 80)
    text_font = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 35)
    size = (WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Dots And Boxes")

#enter your name --> invite a player --> accept/decline --> accept --> going in a place to chat and ready up --> picking a map --> play --> end game --> play again/exit

    client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)  # instantiate
    client_socket.connect((host, port))  # connect to the server
    Get_Images(client_socket)
    save_images()

    enter_name_function(screen, client_socket)

    play_again = True
    while (play_again == True):
        map = pickamap(screen, client_socket)
        print map
        message = receive_a_message(client_socket)
        print message
        label = text_font_waiting.render("Waiting...", True, (0,0,0))
        screen.blit(label, (75, 145))
        pygame.display.flip()
        if message == "no":
            start_new_thread(wait_to_receive, (client_socket,))
            global continue_var
            while not continue_var:
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                            client_socket.close()
                            pygame.quit()
        game_function(screen,client_socket,text_font)
    client_socket.close()  # close the connection


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

# client_socket.send(message.encode())  # send message
# data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()  # receive response
```

this is the server code

```
from socket import *
import sys
from thread import *
import random
import time
from ClientClass import client_values

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 8888
connected_clients = []
game_clients = []
map_pick = []

start = "openscreen.png"
win = "win.png"
lose = "Lose.png"
lobby = "lobby.png"
Board3 = "threeonthree.png"
Board4 = "fouronfour.png"
pick = "pick.png"
disconected = "Opponentdis.png"
images_arr = [start, win, lose, lobby, Board3, Board4, pick, disconected]


def send_images(client_socket):
    for image in images_arr:
        with open('serverimg/' + image, 'rb') as current_file:
            file_data = current_file.read()
            message_length = str(len(file_data))
            message_length = str(message_length.ljust(64, ' ')) # adds blank spaces so that the total length is 64 bytes
            client_socket.send(message_length.encode('utf-8'))
            client_socket.send(file_data) # dont need encode because its already in bytes

def send_pic_files(client_socket):
    arr_img = [start, win, lose, lobby, Board3, Board4, pick, disconected]
    for img in arr_img:
        img_handle = ""
        with open(img, "rb") as f:
            img_handle = bytearray(f.read())
        data = "pic:" + "1:" + "answer:" + img.split("/")[-1]
        client_socket.send(data)
        print(data)
        client_socket.recv(1024)
        client_socket.send(img_handle)
        client_socket.recv(1024)

def recive_a_map(client):
    map = int(client.recv(1))
    print map
    return map

def send_a_map(client,map):
    time.sleep(0.10)
    print map
    client.send(str(map))


def build_a_message(turn,place1,place2):
    # your turn / his turn / 0 which means disconnected | win / lose else blank | place of the other guy placement / blank | his points | your points
    return str(turn) + "|" + str(place1) + "|" + str(place2) +"@"

def send_a_message(client,message):
    time.sleep(0.05)
    print message
    client.send(str(message))

def receive_a_message(client):
    time.sleep(0.10)
    message = client.recv(1024)
    print message
    message = message.split("|")
    place1 = message[0]
    place2 = message[1]
    score = message[2]
    return place1, place2, int(score)


# Function for handling connections. This will be used to create threads
def twoclientthread(client1,client2,map1,map2):
    client_1_ready = False
    client_2_ready = False
    client1.settimeout(0.1)
    client2.settimeout(0.1)
    while (True):
        message = ""
        try:
            message = client1.recv(1024)
        except:
            pass
        if message == "ready":
            client_1_ready = True
            print "client_1_ready"

        message = ""
        try:
            message = client2.recv(1024)
        except:
            pass
        if message == "ready":
            client_2_ready = True
            print "client_2_ready"
        if client_1_ready and client_2_ready:
            break

    client1.settimeout(None)
    client2.settimeout(None)


    placements_array = []
    score = 0
    place = 0
    if map1 != map2:
        if map1 > map2:
            map = random.randint(map2, map1)
        if map1 < map2:
            map = random.randint(map1, map2)
    else:
        map = map1
# receive a map
    send_a_map(client1, map)
    send_a_map(client2, map)
# start game
    gameended = False
    anotherturn = True
    while score < 9 and gameended != True:
        while anotherturn == True and gameended != True:
            anotherturn = False
            try:
                print anotherturn
                send_a_message(client1, build_a_message("Your turn", 0, 0))
                send_a_message(client2, build_a_message("His turn", 0, 0))
                place1, place2, newscore = receive_a_message(client1)
                send_a_message(client2, build_a_message("His turn", place1, place2))

                if int(newscore) > score:
                    place1 = 0
                    place2 = 0
                    anotherturn = True
                    score = newscore
            except:
                send_a_message(client2, build_a_message(0,0,0))
                gameended = True


        anotherturn = True
        while anotherturn == True and gameended != True:
            try:
                anotherturn = False
                send_a_message(client2, build_a_message("Your turn", 0,0))
                send_a_message(client1, build_a_message("His turn", 0, 0))
                place1, place2, newscore = receive_a_message(client2)
                placements_array.append((place1,place2))
                send_a_message(client1, build_a_message("His turn", place1, place2))
                print anotherturn
                print newscore
                if int(newscore) > score:
                    place1 = 0
                    place2 = 0
                    anotherturn = True
                    score = int(newscore)

            except:
                send_a_message(client1, build_a_message(0, 0, 0))
                gameended = True

def run_a_game(client):
    game_clients.append(client)
    map = recive_a_map(client)
    map_pick.append(map)
    if len(map_pick) != 0 and len(map_pick) % 2 != 0:
        send_a_message(client, "no")
        while True:
            if len(map_pick) != 0 and len(map_pick) % 2 == 0:
                print "yeshhhhhhh"
                send_a_message(client, "yes")
                break
    else:
        send_a_message(client, "yes")



def wait_to_start_game():
    finish = False
    while finish != True:
        if len(map_pick) != 0 and len(map_pick) % 2 == 0:
            time.sleep(0.10)
            start_new_thread(twoclientthread, (game_clients[len(game_clients) - 2], game_clients[len(game_clients) - 1], map_pick[len(map_pick) - 2],map_pick[len(map_pick) - 1],))
            finish = True


can_continue = False
def handle_client(client):
    global can_continue
    start_new_thread(get_a_name, (client,))
    finish = False
    while not finish:
        if(can_continue != False):
            start_new_thread(run_a_game, (client,))
            finish = True
            can_continue = False

def get_a_name(conn):
    global can_continue
    name = conn.recv(1024)
    print name
    client = client_values(conn, name)
    connected_clients.append(client)
    can_continue = True

def main():
    client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    print 'Socket created'
    try:
        client_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    except socket.error as e:
        print e
        sys.exit()
    print 'Socket bind complete'

    start_new_thread(wait_to_start_game, ())
    while len(connected_clients) < 10:
        # Start listening on socket
        client_socket.listen(10)
        print 'Socket now listening'
        # now keep talking with the client
        # wait to accept a connection - blocking call
        conn, addr = client_socket.accept()
        send_images(conn)
        print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])
        start_new_thread(handle_client, (conn,))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Too much code. Can you [edit] your question and bring the code down to a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

By using `client.setblocking(False)` you can retrieve data from the socket while in your main loop using something like this :

```
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((host, port))
client.setblocking(False) # Prevent socket from waiting for input

# ...

try:
  raw_data = client.recv( 1024 )
except BlockingIOError:
  pass
```

This also drops the need for Threading if you would like.